# Tensor product of von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

We know that a Type II$_\infty$ factor can be written as a tensor product of a Type II$_1$ factor and a Type I$_\infty$ factor. Is there any explicit example of II$_\infty$ factor constructed this way?

Second question: what is the algebra of the tensor product of a Type II$_1$ factor and a Type I$_n$ factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean by "explicit" here. Take any II$_1$ factor $N$, any infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$, and form $M=N\otimes B(H)$. Then $M$ is II$_\infty$.

As for your second question, for a II$_1$-factor $N$ you have a canonical isomorphism
$$
N\otimes M_n(\mathbb C)\simeq M_n(N). 
$$
And it's easy to see that $M_n(N)$ is a II$_1$-factor for any $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to vN algebra so I am just wondering if this tensor product is the usual/canonical way to build a type $\text{II}_\infty$ factor. Do people take the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n(N)$ to obtain a Type $\text{II}_\infty$ factor?

Comment: No, you do the von Neumann algebra product between the von Neumann algebra $N$ and the von Neumann algebra $B(H)$.

Comment: I mean, you can write a II$_\infty$-factor as an inductive limit of $M_n(N)$ for a certain II$_1$-factor $N$, but it is not a useful point of view as far as I can tell.